# Is group extension unique?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, semidirect-product, group-extensions

Definition: Given groups N and H, a group is said to be an extension of H by N
if there exists $N_{0}\vartriangleleft G$ such that $N_{0}\cong N$
and $G/N_{0}\cong H$
We know that a normal subgroup of a group is not unique. Then extension of a group is not uniquely determined. But I dont find example. Can you give me an example for that $N_0$ is not unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_2$ is an extension of $\mathbb Z_4$ by $\mathbb Z_2$ as well as an extension of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ by $\mathbb Z_2$. For the first, $N_0$ is generated by $(0,1)$, and for the second it is generated by $(2,0)$.

If you want to keep $H$ the same, let's go back to the $\mathbb{Z}_4$ by $\mathbb{Z}_2$ example. You get the same isomorphism class of extensions if you choose the subgroup generated by $(2,1)$.

Comment: Thank you. For the same groups N and H, can we find two different $N_0$ groups?

Comment: @MrDoctor Yes. Let me update my answer.

Comment: @MRDoctor Please see the update.

Comment: Let $N_{0}=<(2,1)>=\{(0,0),(2,1)\}$, then $\mathbb{Z}_{4}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}/N_{0}=\{\{(0,0),(2,1)\},\{(0,1),(2,0)\},\{(1,0),(3,1)\},\{(1,1),(3,0)\}\}$,
but I can't find isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_{4}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}/N_{0}$
and $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @MrDoctor Note that the group is cyclic, generated by $(1,0)$. $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(3,0)$ are all in different cosets, and these are all of the cosets. So it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$.